# how to conditionally assign variable - nunjucks

Tags: html, templates, nunjucks

I want to assign the variable that's exists and not `undefined` like how the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is done in Javascript

```
<label for="dummy-xyz">{{ data.dummy.id || dummy.id }}</label>
```

I'm unable to do it with the `||` operator however

Comment: Use `or` and `and` instead `||` and `&&`, e.g. `{{ data.dummy and data.dummy.id or dummy.id }}`.